# GET.DOCUMENT(10) (ExecuteExcel4Macro) closed Excel Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I wanna extract lastRow from a closed workbook using the XML function ExecuteExcel4Macro. Debug.print returns "Error 2042" ~ #N/A. I suppose it has something to do with my filepath. I've tried different approaches (W & W/O ' and "), but nothing seems to work. The documentation on GET.DOCUMENT is so limited, nevertheless I found this [link](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/VBA_in_Excel/_XL4-Makros_in_VBA_verwenden) - which shows almost the same exsample

**Code**

*1 = sheetname, GET.DOCUMENT(10) = lastrow*

```
 Debug.Print ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(10,""'C:\Users\Unicco\Desktop\[Filter.xlsx]1'"")")
```

**Error**

```
Error 2042
```

Maybe one of you guys can see what's wrong.

(I know there are many other approches towards extracting data from Opened / Closed Workbooks, but I'd love to get this function to work)

**EDIT:**
Based on answer, I ended up using this:

```
ExecuteExcel4Macro("COUNTA('C:\Users\Unicco\Desktop\[Filter.xlsx]1'!R1C1:R1048576C1)")
```

Comment: Your final code assumes there are no gaps in the column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `GET.DOCUMENT` with a closed workbook. Per the help, the syntax is:

GET.DOCUMENT(type_num, name_text)

where "Name_text    is the name of an **open document** . If name_text is omitted, it is assumed to be the active document." (emphasis added)